# Strange behavior of email campaign

Tags: email, mailmerge

We are experiencing a strange email campaign issue, and hopefully someone may have some idea of why this is happening.

Our SaaS product allows customer to create personalized content micro-sites. A customer can use a "dynamic" link which we provide in their email campaign/mail merge tools. For example, we provide something like:

> [https://oursass.com/?email={email}&firstname={firstname}&lastname={lastname}](https://oursass.com/?email=%7Bemail%7D&firstname=%7Bfirstname%7D&lastname=%7Blastname%7D)

This is inserted into a message template for an email campaign, and that software repalces the tokens `{email}`, `{firstname}` and `{lastname}` with the appropriate personalized values.

When a campaign recipient receives the email and clicks on the link, then our SaaS software receives the request and uses the real `email`, `firstname` and `lastname` of the recipient, and we generate a personalized micro-site.

Now the strange part: A few months ago we had a customer complain because they saw a lot of micro-sites generated (like 100 or so) with partially random text for the three tokens; things like the name "Byfkbaeeb Zvemfjfxv" and email "byfkbaeeb.zvemfjfxv@spxflow.com". I said partially random because the name seems to be random, but the same text is used in the email, and the email domain is real.

We were never able to find a reason for this. They were using MS Outlook mail-merge, and we could not find any issues with their input data.

Then, just this week, another customer faced the same issue, with "random" text very similar to the previous customer. In this case, they are using Outplay for their email campaigns.

The only other information I have is that in both cases, the personalized micro-sites were generated in a pattern: Several at or near the same time, then a gap, then several again near the same time, a gap, etc. I know that email campaign tools generally use this type of pattern when sending emails. So, this indicates that we're getting the request at essentially the same time as the email is sent, which indicates it is not humans clicking on the links, but instead the email generated and the link "clicked on" by the same automated process.

Is it possible that some system is "testing" the links in outgoing email, perhaps to check that they're valid? But would such a system generate random/fake data for the URL's query parameters?

I know that there is very little information here, but at this point I'm just fishing for answers from anywhere. :-)

Any help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated!